# How to communicate between two classes

Tags: python

I have a confusion accessing the methods from one class to the other. I want to write on tkinter text widget on class A from inside the method of class B. How am I supposed to do it?

```
from abc import xyz
from Tkinter import *
class A(Frame):
    def write(self,text):
        self.display.insert(END,text+'\n')

    def __init__(self,parent):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent=parent            
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.grid(row=0,sticky=N+E+S+W)
        self.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.display = Text(self)
        self.display.grid(row=0,sticky=N+E+S+W)
        self.yscroll = Scrollbar(self,command=self.display.yview)
            self.yscroll.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=N+S)
            self.display.config(yscrollcommand=self.yscroll.set)

class B(xyz):
    def dataReceived(self):
        data = 'hello world'
        get = A()
        get.write(data + '\n')

def main():

    root = Tk()
    ex = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

This gives me error as

```
get = A()
exceptions.TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Please suggest me the way to inherit the properties of class A in Class B. Thank You for taking time to read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't communicating between two classes, your problem is that you forgot to give the `A` class an argument. Note  the `parent` argument:

```
def __init__(self,parent):
    Frame.__init__(self,parent)
    self.parent=parent            
    self.initUI()
```

Comment: when I use parent argument I get,`exceptions.NameError: global name 'parent' is not defined` error.

Comment: That's because the parent variable doesn't exist.  If you don't want to pass a parent, use `def __init__(self,parent=None):`

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to pass a parent, in class A change __init__() to :

```
def __init__(self,parent=None):
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the units (text and parent)  when you first make the class.  So it would be `get = A(data + "/n",  "some str"` 
The you could run the get.function without giving any parameters.

Also I'm not sure of you are aware but you are adding two new lines to data not just one